# Warning: str_repeat() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given in

Tags: php, wordpress

Check live(on the bottom)- http://cchoco.net/2014/03/01/un-appareil-photo-dans-une-maison-hantee/

Error- `Warning: str_repeat() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given in /home3/philpaol/public_html/cchoco.net/wp-content/thesis/boxes/tl-custom-php/box.php on line 56`

Code of box.php page(line 53 to line 61)-

```
public function html($depth) {
    global $thesis;

    $tab = str_repeat("\t", !empty($depth) ? $depth : 0);
    echo
        "$tab<div" . ($this->options[ 'id' ] ? ' id="' . trim( $thesis->api->esc( $this->options[ 'id' ] ) ) . '"' : '' ) . ' class="' . ( $this->options[ 'class' ] ? trim( $thesis->api->esc( $this->options[ 'class' ] ) ) : 'cus_code' ) . "\">\n" .
        "$tab\t" . trim( apply_filters( $this->_id, eval( '?>' . stripslashes( $this->options[ 'code' ] ) . '<?php ' ) ) ) . "\n" .
        "$tab</div>\n";
}
```

Comment: show us where you're calling the function, you seem to be passing an array as `$depth`.

Comment: is `$depth` integer value always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `$depth` variable is an array when the function is expecting an integer

check the `$depth` variable
and to avoid this error from poping up you can change

```
str_repeat("\t", !empty($depth) ? $depth : 0)
```

to

```
str_repeat("\t", !empty($depth) && is_long($depth) ? $depth : 1)
```

this way if an array is passed it will just set the second parameter to 1.

you can also test the `$depth` variable prior to passing it to the `str_repeat` function by calling

```
$depth = is_array($depth) ? array_shift($depth) : $depth;
```

or instead of `array_shift` retrieve the desired value from the array if it is not the first index of that array...

Comment: This will remove the PHP error but it will break the function.

Comment: revised the answer to include a check for arrays

Comment: it shouldn't break the function as it will treat this case as if no depth was passed (it will set it to 0), he already had that as a case in his function by calling `!empty($depth) ? $depth : 0` bit

Comment: 0 is not an appropriate value for the intention of the function. Having code that produces no warnings is not the same as having code that works.

Comment: No, he should use the current depth value. It is wrong to assume the current depth value is 0 or 1 or the first value of the array. More information is needed (ie - what is passing the array and what is the array) before the original problem can be addressed.

Comment: that's why I mentioned the bit about replacing the `array_shift` if it is not the first value in the array. he can do that check himself.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it says - `$depth` is an array. Consider using `intval($depth)`, and also define your function like so:

```
function html($depth=0)
```

Comment: This will just break the function. Running intval() on an array will just return 0 or 1, not the depth value they need for the function to work properly.